# emu8086 disassembled code not showing up, am i missing something?

Tags: emulation, emu8086

when you emulate your code in emu8086, there is a window called emulator:noname.com_ that shows information on the left and right window that u can scroll up and down.
On my emu8086 when i emulate;

```
mov al, 55

mov bl, 44

add al, bl

hlt
```

i see the left scroll up and down window with information in it but the window on the right is blank, i tried scrolling up and down but theres nothing. i also tried clicking on the orioginal source code in a different window.

Comment: I don't have emu8086 currently installed, but if that window on the right would be the output window then a blank window would be normal as this program doesn't output anything at all.

Comment: Insert next instructions directly below the addition: `mov bx,7` `mov ah,0Eh` `int 10h` `mov ah,00h` `int 16h` This code will print the "c" character and wait until you press a key.